# Should I import the "main" library or the submodule of the previous library?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the `json.loads()` method from my Flask methods. Since the `json` library was not imported yet, my IDE asked if should import `Flask.json` or `json`.  I chose `Flask.json` but is there a "best practice"?

Which to import?

[image]

I'm basically asking if I should import json or Flask.json and why?

Comment: The json.loads() are ordered by their popularity in 40,000 open source Python projects.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to communicate to me, I will add an edit explaining further what I am asking.

Comment: Also can someone help me and edit the link to "preview" the image please. By "preview" I mean show the image rather than a hyperlink tot he image.

Comment: For those who work with flask, it is better to use flask.json instead of json

Comment: @Salio Yes,  and for those looking for "why"  see accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#module-flask.json), `flask.json` imports `simplejson` first, and if `simplejson` does not exist, it defaults back to the stdlib `json`. `flask.json` provides more functionalities than stdlib `json`, specifically for web development. Therefore, I would go for `flask.json`. I mean the fact that Flask developer took the time to write a wrapper on top of a stdlib module probably is a good hint that we shall use `flask.json` instead of `json` when working with Flask.

Comment: Thank you that explanation made sense